# How to create different array's value while looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops

when i load this function the value of the array's all the same .. How can i make different array's value everytime i load this function ? btw the num1, num2, opt1, opt2 .. is a random number from

```
random = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 15)
}
```

please help me guys :)this is my code ..

```
makeQuestion = () => {
    questions = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        var obj = {
        'question': `Berapakah ${num1} ${operator} ${num2} ?`, 
        'choice1' : `${opt1}`, 
        'choice2': `${opt2}`,
        'choice3': `${opt3}`,
        'choice4': `${final}`,
        'answerIndex' : `${2}`,
        }
        questions.push(obj)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please fix the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), don't post images of code/errors, don't add unnecessary stuff (e.g. "please help") - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why _would_ they be different? You're adding the same values in each iteration. `num1` for instance will keep the same value unless you change it in your for-loop.

Comment: btw the num1, num2, opt1, opt2 .. is a random number from random = () => { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) }  i want to make a random value ..

Comment: Then assign those random numbers inside of your loop. If you assign the random value once to `num1` and then loop keeping that number the same, it will be the same for every object to add to your array.

Comment: i think you're right okay thanks for your reply i'll try it .. :)